# WPF: xceed datagrid, how to adjust column width at runtime?

Tags: wpf, xaml, xceed-datagrid, xceed

I'm trying to adjust the xceed datagrid at runtime and cannot find a setting for this, anyone have any experience with it?

Answer (score 2):

I am using Xceed's DataGridControl and its exactly as Matt sketched it. If your control is named dgCtrl, the code behind would look like this:

```
dgCtrl.Columns[0].Width = 100; // Sets the column's width to 100px.
```

You can also use the column names (*FieldName* property) to access the Columns:

```
dgCtrl.Columns["Address"].Width = 100;
```

Xceed's grid offers various options to adjust the width of the columns automatically at run-time. Refer to their [online documentation](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWpfDataGrid/Column_Positions_and_Widths.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the xceed datagrid, but does it not have a columns property like the normal one?

```
dataGrid.Columns[2]...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach (Xceed.Grid.Column column in grdInterstitialView.Columns)
 {
      column.Width = (int)(column.GetFittedWidth() * 1.1M);
 }
```

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.